# Torch / Lua, how to edit an original abstract file of a known package?

Tags: lua, torch

I tried to add a function to the `Module.lua` [abstract file](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/Module.lua) in the Torch package called `nn`, but my main program does not find it.

Suppose my function is simply:

```
function printTry()
  print("printTry()");
end
```

I added this function at the end of the `Module.lua` file and I was supposed to use it in my Torch terminal:

```
require 'nn';
perceptron = nn.Module();
perceptron:printTry()
```

But the system generates:

```
string "perceptron.printTry();"]:1: attempt to call field 'printTry' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [string "perceptron.printTry();"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/davide/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:668: in function 'repl'
    ...vide/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x004064d0
```

Probably the system is not aware of this new function that I added... what should I do to use this new method?

Answer (score 1):

Use torch.getmetatable:

```
require 'nn'
torch.getmetatable('nn.Module').printTry = function() print('PrintTry') end

perceptron = nn.Sequential()
perceptron:printTry()
```

Comment: Thanks @smhx, it works! Do you also know how I could access to the self fields without using `self`?

Comment: Hey @smhx, what to do if I wanted to use the `self` field?

Answer (score 0):

You simply defined a global function `printTry`, but you call it as a method on `perceptron`. You need to define it as a field of `Module` (in that `Module.lua` file, assuming this is what `nn.Sequential` returns):

```
function Module:printTry()
  print("printTry()")
end
```

Comment: Hi Paul. `Sequential` might be wrong so I restarted from `Module.lua`. Unfortunately it does not work. I tried to insert your code at the bottom of Module.lua, and then ran: `require 'nn'; mod = nn.Module();  mod:printTry();`, but it gives the same error...

Comment: Actually, `Sequential` inherits from `Module`, so either call should work. Do other methods from the `Module` class work? for example, `listModules`? Are you updating the right file? ;) What if you rename one of the existing methods, does renamed method work?

Comment: Thanks @PaulKulchenko. Actually, I tried to rename some methods of my `Module.lua` file but the system does not recognize my change: all the renamed methods do no work. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you are updating the wrong file? In any case, if Soumith's (@smhx) changes are working for you, that's a better way as it doesn't require source file changes.

Comment: It's possible that I'm updating the wrong file, but it's very strange since I have only one `Module.lua` file. @smhs solution works partially, because the new function that I'm implementing would use the `self` field in `Module.lua`, while it cannot use `self` in the @smhs implementation. Do you have any ideas on how to correctly use a replacement of `self`? Thanks